# GetResponse() takes 500ms on my PC, 10ms on others

Tags: c#, web-services

I have sent many http requests in cycle with

```
WebRequest request = (WebRequest)WebRequest.Create(str);
```

This line takes about **500ms** on my computer

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

On other computers on the network: **10-20ms**

how to fix this bug?
What reasons could there be for other computers on the network completing their request faster?

There is no proxy installed, and the request is to `127.0.0.1:port`.

code for log

```
String IdHTTPUt_Get(string str)
         {
            string res="";
             
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
             
WriteLog("begin");
           
WriteLog((DateTime.Now - dt).ToString()); dt = DateTime.Now;
           
 WebRequest request = (WebRequest)WebRequest.Create(str);
            
WriteLog((DateTime.Now - dt).ToString()); dt = DateTime.Now;
             
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(opt_Utor_User,opt_Utor_Password);

request.Method = "GET";
            
WriteLog((DateTime.Now - dt).ToString()); dt = DateTime.Now;
           
request.Proxy = null;
            
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
           
{
                
  WriteLog((DateTime.Now - dt).ToString()); dt = DateTime.Now;
                
  Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                
  WriteLog((DateTime.Now - dt).ToString()); dt = DateTime.Now;
                
  StreamReader readStream = new
 
  StreamReader(receiveStream,Encoding.UTF8);
               
  WriteLog((DateTime.Now - dt).ToString()); dt = DateTime.Now;
                
  res = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                
  WriteLog((DateTime.Now - dt).ToString()); dt = DateTime.Now;
                
  receiveStream.Close();                 
  readStream.Close();
             
}
            
WriteLog((DateTime.Now - dt).ToString()); dt = DateTime.Now;
           
return res;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Which line is taking the time - `WebRequest.Create` or `request.GetResponse()`?

Are you disposing of the response at the end? It should be within a using statement:

```
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    ...
}
```

The connection pool limits the number of connections you can make to any particular host - in this case you would end up waiting for the garbage collector to release an earlier response. That *may* not be the problem, but I wouldn't be surprised to find it was.

EDIT: Of course, the other possibility is that it's just taking a long time to process the request on your machine. What is the request doing? If you make the same request *from* other machines (but still to your machine) how long does that take?

Comment: begin

00:00:00.0050003

00:00:00

00:00:00

00:00:00.5270301

00:00:00

00:00:00

00:00:00

00:00:00

Comment: (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse() takes 527ms

Comment: from other mashine to local( utorrent web api ) adn to remote mashine work fine.
some bug in IE ( is request processed with IE?)..